# jQuery Datatable: Heading and Search on the same line

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

At the moment my jQuery Datatable looks like this:

[image: Picture]

and I would like to have the History heading and the search bar on the same line.

I have implemented the heading and table like this:

```
<h2>History</h2>
<table class="table" id="history_tbl" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            ...
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @for (var i = 1; i < M.Count(); i++)
        {
        <tr>
            ...
        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And the following specifications for the Datatable:

```
$("#history_tbl").DataTable({
                "columns": [
                    { searchable: false },
                    null,
                    { searchable: false },
                    { searchable: false },
                    { searchable: false },
                    { searchable: false },
                    { searchable: false }
                ],
                ordering: false,
                paging: true,
                lengthChange: false,
                language: {
                    searchPlaceholder: "Search names",
                    search: ""
                }
            });
```

I've seen that I can change something by adding DOM, but I'm not quite sure what I need in my case.

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two options - both of which are less than ideal:

**Option One**

One approach, using the [`dom`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) option that you mentioned, is this:

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
  dom: '<"title"<"filter"f>>rtip'
} );
```

This places the `f` filter control in its own div with a style class of `filter`, and then also wraps that in another div with a style class of `title`.

Then we need the following style section in the `<head>` of the HTML page:

```
.title::before {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 1.5em 0 0 0;
  content: "History";
}

.filter {
  float: right;
}
```

Finally, the `<h2>History</h2>` element needs to be removed from your page, to use this approach.

My end result is this:

[image]

This approach has a couple of important drawbacks:

1. It forces you to place some content (the heading) in CSS - whereas style and content are supposed to be kept separate.
2. This could make it harder to implement internationalization (if that is needed).

**Option Two**

Alternatively, you can use the `<h2>` tag, with some relative positioning - for example:

```
<div style="position: relative; top: 30px;"><h2>History</h2></div>
```

This pushes the title down from the top by 30px (you may need to adjust that to your specific needs).

In this case you do not need to use the `<dom>` option, or the related styles from the first option.

This also has some important drawbacks:

1. It can be brittle - having unexpected/unwanted behavior in some situations (e.g. different screen resolutions).
2. You may have an unwanted gap of white space at the top of the page, which requires additional styling work-arounds to remove.

Comment: Thank you for that detailed answer! It works fine, although I understand those drawbacks you mentioned.