# Align search bar and title in table using datatable package in R

Tags: html, css, r, dt

I've searched extensively online and haven't found a solution for this using reactable, datatable, or formattable. I'm trying to create a table where the title of the table is aligned with the search bar. In all examples that I've seen, the search bar creates it's own row so you can't have the title in that same row so they're never even. [image: Table example]

Here is the code I have so far:

```
    datatable(iris,
              options = list(dom = 'ft'),
              caption = htmltools::tags$caption(style = 'caption-side: top;
                                                text-align: left;
                                                color:black;
                                                font-size:24px;
                                                font-weight: bold;', "My title"))
```

Comment: You may get some ideas from [jQuery Datatable: Heading and Search on the same line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64097670/12567365). Neither option is great. (You would also need to adapt the approaches from plain DataTables-in-a-web-page to DataTables-in-r).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @andrewJames! This helped me get started. If using a Shiny app, add the following code to your css file so that the text is aligned with the search bar of a dataTable. Note that the title and table are separate. It is not a title defined in dataTable.

```
#table-title {
  position: relative; top: 60px;
}
```

Where #table-title is in your ui. For example:

```
fluidRow(column(width = 12, align = "left", div(id = "table-title", textOutput("table_title")))),

fluidRow(column(width = 12, align = "left", div(id = "my-table", dataTableOutput("my_table"))))
```